# Django form with just a BooleanField

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm rather new to Django and I'm using Django 1.0.
I have this:
forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    extra_cheeze = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                      initial=False,
                                      label='Extra cheeze')
```

views.py:

```
def order_something(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        # do stuff...
```

The problem is that the form is not valid unless the checkbox is checked, so there doesn't seem to be a way to get a False value from the field. 
As far as I can understand from [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield), it should work. It works if I add a CharField to my form...

Am I misunderstanding something here or is this a bug? (Yes, I have googled but found nothing relevant)

**Update:** As suggested by @Dominic Rodger, I tried adding a hidden field
`dummy = forms.CharField(initial='dummy', widget=forms.widgets.HiddenInput())`
and that makes the form valid. This workaround enables me to move on right now, but it would still be interesting to know if I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: Huh. Sounds like a bug to me. Could you workaround it using a hidden field?

Comment: There have been a few bug reports which sounds kinda similar - see http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=django+checkbox+forms+bug

Comment: I will try. I suspect that the Form doesn't like the empty data, since the browser won't include the field for an unchecked checkbox.

Comment: I'd file this as a bug in Django, since I can't see any valid reason why my suggested change would fix it. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/#id1

Comment: It works for me without the workaround (but I add a submit button to the form html) with django 1.0.2 and FF 3.0.14 and IE7.  Which version of django and browser are you using?  Are you using an html form with submit button, or ajax to submit the form?

Comment: @dar - interesting. Niklas, what version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was a bug in the code in my question. Thanks to @d0ugal for helping me spot it by including a slightly different example.  The problem was here:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST or None) # <- PROBLEM HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
    # do stuff...
```

The bug was that I assumed that request.POST would evaluate to True if it was a post. But since browsers don't post anything for a not-checked checkbox, and that was the only field, the POST data was an empty dictionary, which evaluates to False. This caused None to be used as initialization data, causing the form to be unbound and not valid.
@d0ugal's example does the safe thing and tests request.method first.

Answer (score 4):

This also works for me on 1.1, 1.0.3 and 1.0 (I have these three Virtual environments setup). I only tested this in FireFox so if its a browser issue thats another matter but as far as I know they all handle POST data with checkboxes the same.

Here is the full code for the project so you can reproduce at your leisure and compare with yours to see the difference.

Setting up in Ubuntu

```
$ django-admin.py startproject testing
$ cd testing/
$ python manage.py startapp myfirst
```

Then in the myfirst app folder;

**/myfirst/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from myfirst.forms import MyForm

def testing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            result = "valid"
        else:
            result = "not valid"
    else:
        form = MyForm()
        result = "no post"

    return render_to_response('test.html', {'form':form, 'result':result,})
```

**/myfirst/forms.py**
from django import forms

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    extra_cheeze = forms.BooleanField(required=False,initial=False,label='Extra cheeze')
```

**/myfirst/templates/test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="." method="POST">
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="test">
    </form>
    {{ result }}
</body>
</html>
```

**/urls.py**
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

```
from myfirst.views import testing

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'.*', testing),
)
```

Then just run the project $ python manage.py runserver and browse to http://localhost:8000/. You'll actually find that required doesn't do anything with the checkbox, since you can't leave it blank - a 'blank' answer is effectively 'no'. If you want to make sure a user selects an answer have a multiple choice where the user has to select yes or no. You could force them to answer with radio buttons too.

Comment: Actually, the default for 'required' is True, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required.

But your answer made me spot my bug, so +1 for that! I'll answer my own question to make it clear to future readers what the problem was...

Comment: I never said the default for required was True or False :) I just said it doesn't make a different since its impossible to leave a checkbox 'blank' its either selected or not selected. So, there is always a value - being required or not wont make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, it describes the Django behaviour only.

Django 3.0.7 on Python 3.8.4rc1, Debian 10/testing.

My scenario is html `<form>` with more django forms.Form rendered classes inside, one of them has BooleanField only. (There are other small `<forms>` in page like a search form).

```
class OrderInvoiceTypeForm(forms.Form):
    is_business = forms.BooleanField(label="business", initial=False)  # with or without required=False
```

I submit via submit button which IS NOT in OrderInvoiceTypeForm but IS in the html .

With required=False form is always valid and is_business key is in .cleaned_data.

Without required (or with =True):

checked:

```
form_with_boolean.is_valid()    # True
form_with_boolean.cleaned_data  # {'is_business': True}
```

unchecked:

```
form_with_boolean.is_valid()    # False
form_with_boolean.cleaned_data  # {}
```

In 2nd case in dev tools I can see that browser (Chrome) doesn't send the is_business value POST variable. Adding of hidden field will not help.