# Django Form Validation for Boolean Values Not Working

Tags: django, forms

I have a simple HTML form that I'm trying to validate with a Django Form. The problem is that Django's form validation will only recognize the value of `is_kit` if it is `'True'`. (When it is `'False'`, it will give an error saying that the field is required. Here is the form:

```
<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="part_id" value="{{ part.id }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="is_kit" value="False" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" value="Add to Cart"/>
</form>
```

And here is the Django form:

```
class AddItemToCartForm(forms.Form):
    part_id = forms.IntegerField()
    is_kit = forms.BooleanField()
```

And here is the relevant part of my view:

```
def post(self, request, id):
    print(request.POST)
    print(request.POST.get('is_kit'))
    form = AddItemToCartForm(request.POST)
    print(form.errors)
```

The output my server gives is here:

```
<QueryDict: {'is_kit': ['False'], 'part_id': ['1'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['X2vkpwG6GJmK79vypFPAveTzVkrxBauJWgfnRvAtJVcZ8NwBokjQhCnfGN9dFFYF']}>
False
<ul class="errorlist"><li>is_kit<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I believe that my template should work because looking at [the source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/forms/fields/#BooleanField), `forms.BooleanField` should convert the string `'False'` in the POST data to a python `False` value.

As I mentioned above, the form validates perfectly if `is_kit` is set to `'True'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield),

> Since all Field subclasses have **`required=True`** by default, the validation condition here is important. If you want to include a boolean in your form that can be either `True` or `False` (e.g. a checked or unchecked checkbox), you must remember to pass in **`required=False`** when creating the **`BooleanField`**.

So, add **`required=False`** in **`BooleanField()`** as,

```
class AddItemToCartForm(forms.Form):
    part_id = forms.IntegerField()
    is_kit = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

**Additional Info**: 
When the checkbox isn't checked, browsers do not send the field in the POST parameters of requests. Without specifying that the field is optional Django will treat it as a missing field when not in the POST parameters.

**Reference** : [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542839/django-form-with-booleanfield-always-invalid-unless-checked)

Comment: This works for me, but I think I'm a bit confused. Wouldn't having it required just mean that there should exist a value in the post data for `is_kit`, True or False? It seems like `required=True` in this case is literally saying that the value must evaluate to `True` 
for the BooleanField?

Comment: Ah, this makes sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `required=False` to your `BooleanField`:

```
class AddItemToCartForm(forms.Form):
    part_id = forms.IntegerField()
    is_kit = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```