# Django - hide "This field is required." for BooleanField

Tags: django, forms, templates

I only want to display a checkbox the user has to click in order to confirm that notice has been taken:

```
class CheckForm(forms.Form):
    confirmed = forms.BooleanField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CheckForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['confirmed'].label = 'I confirm that I have taken notice'
```

The problem now is that my form shows the following label: "This field is required." at the template output. This is also making sense as I call the form like so at my views.py:

```
form = CheckForm(request.POST)
```

Is there any workaround to only hide the mentioned label at my template and keep required=True?
Simply doing required=False at forms.py
or removing request.POST from views.py
is not a solution as this Field is per definition required and "if form.is_valid():" does not validate if request.POST is missing

views.py

```
def check(request):
    form = CheckForm(request.POST)
    user = User.objects.get(user=request.session.get('user'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            user.token_checked = True
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Thanks for your check-up, you are now able to login again.')
            return redirect(reverse('login'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'check.html')
    else:
        if not user.token_checked:
            username = str(user)
            token = str(user.reset_token)
            args = {
                'token': token,
                'username': username,
                'form': form
            }
            return render(request, 'check.html', args)
```

Comment: Can you please share your view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem views.py snippet as been added, thanks for your quick reply :D

Comment: I found something here but does not fully solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542839/django-form-with-booleanfield-always-invalid-unless-checked

Answer (score 0):

Required for a BooleanField does not make sense. A BooleanField can either be true of false, and the representation of false in html forms is an empty checkbox, which is well: empty. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield).

Comment: Okay that might be true but still does not solve the problem as if form.is_valid(): does not validate in that case

Comment: That's the point of the docs I sent, you are supposed to allow empty input on BooleanField with required=False as per the docs says.

Comment: OKay but I still don't get the benefit here. What should I do with a checkbox that is required but the user is not enforced to acknowledge it? Makes no sense to me :(

Comment: Checkbox cannot be required, they by their nature have 2 states, if it was a required field that would mean it has one state only which is true. For it to have 2 states, false and true, you should not make it required. If you require a boolean field required, people cannot proceed to the next step.

Comment: In this specific case the use should be enforced to hit the checkbox as he has to confirm e.g. TOS or so. Anyways thanks for your comment :D

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that is acceptable, I simply do:

```
self.fields['reset_token'].error_messages = {'required': 'My custom message to display'}
```

This sadly does not fully hide the message but at least it's acceptable
if you only want the user to acknowledged some terms of your site/service.